# Why does Print list command change the timezone in r?

Tags: r, timezone, posixct

working in r.
I have a dataframe 'Dives' with lots of columns. The columns with date and time are in JST timezone.

E.g. begdesc : POSIXct, format: "2013-10-27 02:45:40". When I print the first row using the command below, I get the correct output with JST tz.

```
print(Dives$begdesc[1])
[1] "2013-10-27 02:45:40 JST"
print(Dives$endasc[1])
[1] "2013-10-27 09:53:17 JST"
```

but when I print the first row of more than one column as a list, the tz is changed to AWST. Why is this, and how would I get the tz output as per the value in the dataframe?

```
print(c(Dives$begdesc[1],Dives$endasc[1]))
[1] "2013-10-27 01:45:40 AWST" "2013-10-27 08:53:17 AWST"
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you supply the `dput()` of your data so we know exactly what's in your data object. Also what output do you get for `Sys.getlocale()`. This formatting is likely due to your locale settings. Maybe `print(c(Dives$begdesc[1],Dives$endasc[1]), tz="JST")` will do what you want.

Comment: structure(1382809540, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Tokyo")
//
Indeed my sys is on UK, but not AWST..
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
//
print(c(Dives$begdesc[1],Dives$endasc[1]), tz="JST") this doesn't work but tz ="Asia/Tokyo" does.
//almost too simple, so the question is why does r change the timezone on a list print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MrFlick's comment:

```
print(c(Dives$begdesc[1],Dives$endasc[1]), tz="Asia/Tokyo")
```

almost too simple, so the question is why does r change the timezone on a list print, thereby requiring you to tell it what tz the data was in to get the right print?

Comment: The default timezone for `print.POSIXct` is `""`, so that's probably the root cause?